# Url-rewrite with no fixed structure

Tags: php, url-rewriting

i have this 3 url type:

- site.com/page
- site.com/page/action
- site.com/page/action?params

the "page" is always here, but the 2 more is't

how can make it work in this way every time?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)?(.*)$ $1.php?action=$2&$3
```

Whith this one, if the last 2 parts is't here, stop working...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want more than one rule for this (you could do it with one but readability-wise, 2 would be better.

Firstly, forget about the query string. You aren't manipulating it, and the `[QSA]` flag can do the work of appending it to the resulting URL.

You now need two rules, one to deal with the "action" variant, and one to deal with the page name only:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ $0.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1.php?action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

*However*, this will cause a rewrite loop. The way that mod_rewrite works means that the rules will almost always be executed at least twice, and on the second (and all subsequent) iteration the first rule will match the rewritten URL.

So we need to be a little more specific:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:(?!\.php$)[^/])+$ $0.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This lookahead will ensure that the first rule only matches URIs that don't end with `.php`.

Note that the `QSA` flag is only applied to the second rule. This is because it only has an effect when the rewritten URI alters the query string - the default behaviour (when the query string is not altered) is to append the original query string.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

For each rule i have added before:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/.*

This is correct?!

Comment: @DigitalDaigor Those conditions will prevent the rules from applying when the request is to `http://yoursite.com/css/*` or `http://yoursite.com/js/*` - so if that's what you want, then yes they are correct. Note that they could be condensed into a single condition, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(cs|j)s/.*`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?action=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I don't know why... my rewrite rules skills are too low, but this one return error 500 on my server!

Thanks!